# Repositories defined in pom.xml and settings.xml, which one takes precedence during maven build

Tags: maven

Let's say i defined few repositories and pluginrepositories in pom.xml and also defined them in settings.xml. When maven build happens, will it first look for the repositories in local, then settings.xml and then finally pom.xml. Just trying to get the correct precedence order

Answer (score 0):

The repositories are merged.  Run `mvn help:effective-pom` and examine the `<repositories/>` node to determine what is configured from the `pom.xml` and `settings.xml`.

In general, dependencies that have been downloaded are not downloaded again but that behavior is controlled by the `<updatePolicy/>` configuration within the individual `<repository/>` configurations.

Comment: Thanks Allen. So i now have another question. lets say i configured repository.mulesoft.org/releases as a repository in pom.xml and i also configured my artifactory repository in settings.xml. That single artifactory repository is a virtual repository that aggregates many local and remote repositories including repository.mulesoft.org/releases. Now when build runs, and maven reaches out to repository.mulesoft.org/releases, and that endpoint is unreachable etc, will the build fail or will maven then try to next reach out to artifactory repo where the artifact is already cached?

Comment: Maven views each as a repository and doesn't artifactory is a virtual front-end.  Maven will attempt to download from each configured repository until success.  If you look inside your local '~/.m2/repository' you'll see the internal `maven-metadata-REPO.xml` and `resolver-status.properties` associated with the artifacts that keep track of the bookkeeping of download success and last update.

Comment: actually yesterday there was some global outage with repository.mulesoft.org domain
and so in settings.xml we had both repositories configured, the mulesoft one separately as well as artifactory separately.and maven didn't attempt to reach out to artifactory repo while it was attempting to reach out to mulesoft repo directly where it would time out due to 502 bad gateway instead of quickly switching over to artifactory,. that left us with many broken builds.so had to remove mulesoft repos from settings.xml while keeping just artifactory repo there.

Comment: But there are many pom.xml that still has repository.mulesoft.org configured as repository, so i am wondering if we face similar issue, would we need to remove this from pom as well or maven would be smart enough to reach out to artifactory repos that are the only repos defined in settings.xml. Just curious

Comment: I think Maven's logic to assume the repository is configured properly and is available and tries the next repository if the artifact isn't found.  I think setting the `<enabled/>` switch (described [here](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#repositories)) would have helped work around the outages.

Comment: I'm not sure I can make a recommendation on editing the POMs.  I guess it would depend on the needs of any artifact consumers...

Comment: The enable switch was correctly configured for both artifactory repo and these separate mulesoft.org repos depending on if its release or snapshot artifact. The issue was that when maven tried to reach out to mulesoft repo it wouldn't reach out in the first place due to 502 bad gateway and then fail the build right away. since it was anyways of no use and artifactory virtual repo has everything aggregated plus many cached artifacts, we went ahead to clean up all these separate mulesoft repos and that fixed the issue. however some of the poms also have these repos with enabled switch.

Answer (score 0):

Maven heavily relies on Set theory for configuration, dependency resolution. In case of configuration it creates an Union of the two.